# JS - jQuery / How to detect if a Key is Pressed / POLL function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pong

I am making a Ping Pong game in Javascript, and there is a ball bouncing all around the screen and you cannot let it touch the lower border of the wrapper box. (The bouncing ball is not the problem, I have programmed that already)

Here is a code that is supposed to make a **raquet move from left to right when you press the arrow keys**... but what the raquet does is to appear like alot of pixels left or right from the original positon. I mean, it doesn't move fluently, it just appear like 30 or 100 pixels to the left or right.

```
function gameLoop() {

    //**********DETECTS IF LEFT OR RIGHT KEYS ARE PRESSED************

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
            userBoxPosX -= userBoxSpeedX;
       }
       if(e.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
            userBoxPosX += userBoxSpeedX;
       }
    });

    //THE USERBOX IS A DIV THAT WE WILL USE AS RAQUET
    userBox.css('left', userBoxPosX + "px");

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 50); //THIS FUNCTION CALLS ITSELF EVERY 50 milliseconds (20FPS)

}
```

Any Idea of how can I make it move fluently? when you have an arrow key pressed?

Let me know if you need more information or need me to upload the project so you can see it working.

Comment: Have you tried just moving 1 pixel at a time? How far left is it moving per frame?

Comment: You don't need to put `$(document).keydown()` inside the loop. Do it once and the callback will be called every time the user presses a key.

Comment: Look, the variables "userBoxSpeedX" are set in 1, it means, it moves 1 pixels from the original position (userBoxPosX), and it doens't work... 

Barmar, but I can't handle it like a normal event. Because it's a game, it's not an event oriented application. Because at the same time the raquet is moving, the ball is bouncing and collitions are being detected... You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Every 50 ms you bind another handler, so after a few seconds you have hundreds of handlers bound to the `keydown` event. So when you press a key, the handler is run hundreds of times in a row.

You should establish the handler once, outside the game loop. Within your loop you need to use `setTimeout` to return control to the browser between iterations. While it's waiting for the timeout, keypresses will trigger the handler.

I think this should be the basic structure:

```
var userBoxPosX = 0, userBoxLastPosX = null;

function gameLoop() {

    if (userBoxPosX !== userBoxLastPosX) { // Has racquet been moved?
        //THE USERBOX IS A DIV THAT WE WILL USE AS RAQUET
        userBox.css('left', userBoxPosX + "px");
        userBoxLastPosX = userBoxPosX;
    }

}

setInterval(gameLoop, 50); // Call main loop function every 50 ms (20 FPS)

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
        userBoxPosX -= userBoxSpeedX;
   }
   if(e.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
        userBoxPosX += userBoxSpeedX;
   }
});
```

Here's how I think you can implement a 20 FPS auto-repeat:

```
var userBoxDelta = 0;

function gameLoop() {

    if (userBoxDelta != 0) { // is raquet moving?
        //THE USERBOX IS A DIV THAT WE WILL USE AS RAQUET
        userBoxPosX += userBoxDelta;
        userBox.css('left', userBoxPosX + "px");
    }

}

setInterval(gameLoop, 50); // Call main loop function every 50 ms (20 FPS)

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
        userBoxDelta = -userBoxSpeedX;
   }
   if(e.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
        userBoxDelta = userBoxSpeedX;
   }
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
   userBoxDelta = 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry Barmar, I don't want to bother, but could you give me a code example? I didn't understand exactly what you mean.

I tried to put the $(document).keydown() ........ outside the loop. And it seemed to work, but I have to set the speed to 20px or 30px, it means, it will move 20 or 30 pixels everytime I press the key... but there is a way it can move 1 or 2 pixels, but a 20 or 30 frames per second? it will be fluent and fast. If you know what I mean... It's like a movie recorded a 10 FPS being played at 30 FPS, instead of a movie recorded at 30FPS being played at 30FPS...

Comment: Here it is the URL so you can see.

The angry face is the'raquet' and the happy face is the bouncing ball.

http://www.juanbonnett.com/tests/bouncingbox/ 

Look that the bouncing ball is moving fast, but is fluent, but the raquet is not fluent, it just moves alot of pixels per keypress. And it takes alot of time to react

Comment: The structure there looks more like what I wrote than your question. And it seems pretty responsive to me.

Comment: The problem is that the user can't press the key 20-30 times a second. Are you trying to make it repeat fast if the user holds the key down? That's normally implemented by the computer's auto-repeat speed, and it may limit the rate. You'll need to do it youself with both `keydown` and `keyup` handlers to detect the state changes.

Comment: Yea, I modified the code and I put it exactly the way you told me. And it's still unresponsive.

I was wondering if there was a way I can use the same frame rate the bouncing ball has with the raquet, instead of just making it move X pixels per key press. If I want it to be as fluent as the bouncing Happy Face it should be inside the gameLoop function, don't you think?

Comment: Sorry. The way you put it the last time it's not working. The raquet doesn't move.

Let's see if someone else replies, and meanwhile I am gonna try harderm and if I finaly get what I want I will post the answer.

You know... Programmers want our programs to be perfect, and if we're not satisfied, we can't sleep hehehehe

Comment: I see my mistake, I used two different variables. Will fix in a sec.

Comment: Changed `userBoxPosDelta` to `userBoxDelta`.

Comment: BARMAR YOUR LAST THING WORKS LIKE A CHARM. IT'S FINALY BEHAVING THE WAY I WANT.... 10000000000 x10 ^23 THANKS!!!

Visit http://www.juanbonnett.com/tests/bouncingbox/ and see the difference!!

Comment: Now it's TOO FAST, I think.

Comment: Hahaha... it's ok... I will just keep on adjusting the game, it's not complete. It's just a bouncing happy face and and angry face that does nothing exciting... but you already gave me what I needed. Thank you so much . We're done for today!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be like the following:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 37) { //LEFT
            userBoxPosX -= userBoxSpeedX;
            updatePosition();
          }
         if(e.keyCode == 39) { //RIGHT
             userBoxPosX += userBoxSpeedX;
             updatePosition();
          }
      });

function updatePosition() {
    userBox.css('left', userBoxPosX + "px");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... the way you are saying is valid. But what I want is to the Raquet to be the same frame rate as the bouncing ball. This way, what the raquet do is just to move X pixels per KeyPress, and it's not responsive. :( CHECK THIS URL AND SEE HOW THE RAQUET (The angry face) is not fluent as the bouncing ball

http://www.juanbonnett.com/tests/bouncingbox/  -> all because the keypress events are outisde the game loop

Comment: You still don't get it. It doesn't matter where the keypress events are, they only fire the moment the user presses a key. They can't be the same frame rate if the user can't press the key that fast.

Comment: I have simulated the code you mentioned in your first post, and made a method to calculate the difference of calls to the function, then tried the code posted in my reply. The issue remains the same if you make a loop call to the method because it will be incremented with every loop call not by click. As the comment of @Barmar it is dependent on the click not on the loop. You want to move the object not the frame. If you have a frame that is moving based on other function, then that frame should handle it is own objects, and the internal objects should be placed relatively.